# Collect reporting data for each possible combination of filter properties

Tags: c#, object-oriented, entity-framework

Basically I'm looking for a way to improve my code, and avoid making a lot of if statements and parameter combination manually, 'cause I need to return a query result depending in the parameters that were sent.

I've read some posts, and tried some stuffs but nothing that works.

For each if statement and param's combination a report or statistic is generated with the data collected from a data base with EntityFramework according to the params sent and it's displayed in a view to the user.

```
public class MultipleParameterSearch
{
    public string strCod { get; set; }
    public string strRack { get; set; }
    public string strPosi { get; set; }
    public int? strLvl { get; set; }
    public int? intCantMin { get; set; }
    public int? intCantMax { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult MultipleParameterSearch(MultipleParameterSearch multiple)
{
    if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
               //getData method return a IQueryable<Model>
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db).Where(a => a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var q = getData(db).Where(x => x.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && x.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", q);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString())).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi)).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax && a.Partida == multiple.strRack).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax && a.CodProd == multiple.strCod).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString())).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi)).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Partida == multiple.strRack).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi,multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock > 0).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax == null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack == null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi == null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl == null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin == null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod == null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (multiple.strCod != null && multiple.strRack != null && multiple.strPosi != null && multiple.strLvl != null && multiple.intCantMin != null && multiple.intCantMax != null)
    {
        using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var x = getData(db)
                        .Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl) && a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin && a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax).ToList();
                return PartialView("multi", x);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(multiple, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I pasted the version with linq instead of query string

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Once answers are available, you should be careful to edit a question in order not to invalidate answers. It might be better you either write a self-answer or ask a follow-up question. You could also decide whether to accept any of the answers here.

Answer (score 3):

So now basically rewriting the whole answer. As OP asks:

> Basically I'm looking for a way to [...] avoid making a lot of if
>   statements and parameter combination manually

This answer provides an alternate solution to tackle exactly that. Precisely, it is easier to maintain and can be adapted to other models as well.

In the whole code I only found a single special case: If `strPosi` and `strLvl` are set, the `.Where` differs. In all other cases you execute the exact same code.

I divided the whole method in 3 methods. Starting with `GetParamsToExecute`. This method uses `GetProperties` and `GetValue` to dynamically generate a list of all parameters not null. Thus, it can be **reused** for other models as well, but has a **costly** operation with `GetProperties`.

```
private List<string> GetParamsToExecute(object model)
{
    List<string> paramsToExecute = new List<string>();
    foreach (var p in model.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.GetValue(model, null) != null)
        {
            paramsToExecute.Add(p.Name);
        }
    }
    return paramsToExecute;
}
```

Second, I created a method `ExecuteParams`, this method is **model specific** and executes all specific `.Where` clauses for the `MultipleParameterSearch` model. It covers the special case of `strPosi` and `strLvl` in an intial if-statement and covers the rest of the code to execute in a switch case.

```
private IQueryable<Model> ExecuteParams(IQueryable<Model> source, List<string> paramsToExecute, MultipleParameterSearch multiple)
{
    if (paramsToExecute.Contains("strPosi") && paramsToExecute.Contains("strLvl"))
        {
            source = source.Where(a => a.Pieza == String.Concat(multiple.strPosi, multiple.strLvl));
            paramsToExecute.Remove("strPosi");
            paramsToExecute.Remove("strLvl");
        }

        foreach (var p in paramsToExecute)
        {
            switch (p)
            {
                case "strCod":
                    source = source.Where(a => a.CodProd == multiple.strCod && a.Stock > 0);
                    break;
                case "strRack":
                    source = source.Where(a => a.Partida == multiple.strRack && a.Stock > 0);
                    break;
                case "strPosi":
                    source = source.Where(a => a.Pieza.Contains(multiple.strPosi) && a.Stock > 0);
                    break;
                case "strLvl":
                    source = source.Where(a => a.Pieza.Substring(1).Contains(multiple.strLvl.ToString()) && a.Stock > 0);
                    break;
                case "intCantMin":
                    source = source.Where(a => a.Stock >= multiple.intCantMin);
                    break;
                case "intCantMax":
                    source = source.Where(a => a.Stock <= multiple.intCantMax);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "The parameter {0} was not found.",
                        p));
        }
    }

    return source;
}
```

And lastly the actual `MultipleParameterSearch`: (EDIT: Added the proper check and return if no parameter is set)

```
public ActionResult MultipleParameterSearch(MultipleParameterSearch multiple)
{
    var paramsToExecute = GetParamsToExecute(multiple);
    if(!paramsToExecute.Any()) {
        return Json(multiple, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var x = ExecuteParams(getData(db), paramsToExecute, multiple).ToList();
            return PartialView("multi", x);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

It works because whether you execute `.Where(ConditionA && ConditionB)` or `.Where(ConditionA).Where(ConditionB)` makes no difference. As my version adds an iterative approach with the the foreach-loop as well as the performance-killer in `GetParamsToExecute`, it should be less performant than the original. Thus, I'm pretty sure that this is not the optimal solution, but it is easier to maintain then the if cluster before and can be adapted to other models by adding appropriate `ExecuteParams` methods for these models.

If it is adapted for other models it would be better to have a general `ExecuteParams` which is called by every action and then chooses the fitting `ExecuteParamsForModelX` accordingly. This makes your actions uniform and dislocates the execution parts completely.

```
Action1(ModelType1) {
    ExecuteParams(model);
}

Action2(ModelType2) {
    ExecuteParams(model2);
}

ExecuteParams(object model) {
    if(model.GetType().Equals(typeof(ModelType1)) 
    {
        ExecuteParamsForModelType1(model);
    }
    // or switch-case or whatever ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

this is the way I ended up doing it, don't know if it's the best way, but it works

I took this idea from an answer that was posted here but now it's not anymore, 
and Honestly I don't remember who suggested it, I took the foreach loop and adapted to my case, for my point of view the foreach loop is the fasted way, and also I can turn it into a method and dive the code to be reusable as suggested by

> FeRaac and dfhwze

In the case approached by FeRaac about the exception or the difference between `strPosi` and `strLvl` with the rest of the params I changed the way I made the linq so to avoid using `LIKE` in the where clause.

```
public ActionResult MultipleParameterSearch(MultipleParameterSearch multiple)
    {
        //First I declare an empty string in which I'll store the different params
        string whereClause = string.Empty;
        //Here I create an empty string list where I'll add not null params values
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        //Like my data base tables don't have the same names as the params I declare and initialise an string dictionary so I can select the data base table name according the param
        Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"strCod", "CodProd" },
            {"strRack", "Rack" },
            {"strPosi", "Position"},
            {"strLvl", "Level" },
            {"intCantMin", "Stock" },
            {"intCantMax", "Stock" }
        };
        //get model properties
        var pro = multiple.GetType().GetProperties();
        //keep count of the iterated params
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var p in pro)
        {
            if (p.GetValue(multiple, null) != null)
            {
                //if the param is not null I create a string in which I add the table name and the param value
                string whereForThisP = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} " + (p.Name == "intCantMin" ? ">=" : (p.Name == "intCantMax" ? "<=" : "==")) + " @"+count, properties[p.Name]);
                //I add the not null param to the values list
                values.Add(p.GetValue(multiple, null).ToString());
                if (whereClause.Equals(string.Empty))
                {
                   //if whereClause is still ampty just add the string
                    whereClause = whereForThisP;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if not I append a "AND" to the clause
                    whereClause += " and " + whereForThisP;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        //if the clause does not contains "Stock" by default I add it greater than 0
        if (!whereClause.Contains("Stock"))
            whereClause += " and Stock > 0";

        try
        {
            //Here just add to the where clause the predicate string , and the values list converted to array
            var x = getData()
                    .Where(whereClause, values.ToArray()).ToList();
            return PartialView("multi", x);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I documented the code the best I could but in brief I just iterate over the model porperties, evaluate if it's not null, and if that's the case I append to a string variable, the table name, and also append the param value to a list where I store the values to later parse it to an array.

After that sent the string where clause and values array as params to the linq where consult.

Comment: You need to summarise the changes you've made. Otherwise your answer is off-topic.

Comment: @t3chb0t Also, this answer deserves a full review as well :p

Comment: @t3chb0t I added documentation don't know if it's ok this way

Comment: What's missing is some information about how and/or why you wrote this code. For instance you can write which suggestions you've implemented or not etc. Maybe you've made some other changes on your own or found anything else that would be interesting to know?

Comment: @t3chb0t changed it, and sorry again I'm new here, didn't know that one's must be very specific, and I'm not use to it

Comment: Ah, that was my initial approach there. I changed it after I saw your real code though. Glad it helped you.

Comment: @FeRaaC it was you, well mate, thanks very much it did help

Answer (score 2):

### DRY Principle

You should write DRY (don't repeat yourself) code. Each of your if-blocks contains the following pattern:

> ```
> using (ELECTROPEntities db = new ELECTROPEntities())
> {
>     try
>     {
>         var x = getData(db)
>                 .Where(predicate).ToList();
>         return PartialView("multi", x);
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
>     }
> }
> ```

where `predicate` is the only part that is specific to the if-block.

One way to use this pattern is to ask the `MultipleParameterSearch` parameter to return the `predicate` for us.

```
MultipleParameterSearch multiple; // given
var predicate = multiple.GetFilter();
```

The filter should return a specific predicate given its state.

```
public Func<ELECTROPEntity, bool> GetFilter()
{
    if (strCod != null && strRack == null 
        && strPosi == null && strLvl == null 
        && intCantMin == null && intCantMax == null)
    {
        return (entity) => entity => entity.CodProd == strCod && entity.Stock > 0;
    }
    // .. and so on
}
```

`MultipleParameterSearch` can then be implemented with just a couple of lines:

```
public ActionResult MultipleParameterSearch(MultipleParameterSearch multiple)
{
     using (var db = new ELECTROPEntities())
     {
         try
         {
             return PartialView("multi", getData(db).Where(multiple.GetFilter()).ToList());
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
    }
}
```